# How do I match a single double quote (") using excel vba's Like function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using excel's vba to match some numerical ratings.  The rating can include a suffix:

1. **+**    add .25 to the rating
2. **-**  subtract .25 from the rating
3. **"**  add .50 to the rating

So for example if the rating:  **5"**  would really mean 5.5 or 5+ would mean 5.25

I have a simple conditional:

```
if ActiveCell.Characters(i,1).Text Like [123456789+-"] then ...
```

Unfortunately the " produces an invalid character error.  I've tried escaping as follows:

- """
- '"'
- \"
- chr(34)

but can't seem to get the code to work.   Thus, my question: How do you match a single double quote using excel VBA's Like function.

Comment: Also, put the hifen at the start (`"[-123456789+""]"`) or at the end (`"[123456789+""-]"`) or else it'll be interpreted as a range of characters.

Comment: @ssarabando: Good point! Edited my question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes around `Like`, i.e.:

```
...Like "[-123456789+""]"...
```

Basically, when using `Like`, the regex is wrapped in double quotes and the double quote inside it is escaped with a second one.

Note that the `-` (hyphen) needs to be at the start or end of the regex, otherwise it denotes a range of characters. Thanks @ssarabando !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this:  If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Characters(i, 1).Text Like "[123456789+-""]"  but I still get the invalid character error.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: Hm, that's strange. You don't need to offset (0,0), but that shouldn't matter. It certainly works for me here though, using Excel 2010. Check the updated condition in my answer in case it was the hyphen that was giving you problems.

Comment: Ok, will give another try. I'm using Mac 2011 excel, but I would hope it would still work.  Thanks again.

Comment: It was the hyphen. Thanks!